# The image is base64 encoded but cannot be emailed

Tags: java, smtp, base64, git-send-email

This method encodes the image file into base64 and then transmits it.

You will receive a notification that the email attachment has been successfully completed and the transfer was successful.
The base64 encoded value was wrapped with 76 characters each.
However, there are times when emails are delivered normally, and there are times when they are delivered abnormally.
There are no errors.
Is the image size wrong?

```
String base64EncodedImage = base64EncodeImage(sendMailRequestDTO.getFile());
int lineLength = 76;
buf.delete(0, buf.length())
        .append("--boundary_text\r\n")
        .append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"image.png\"\r\n")
        //.append("Content-Type: image/png\r\n")
        .append("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n")
        .append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n")
        .append("--boundary_text\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < base64EncodedImage.length(); i += lineLength) {
            int end = Math.min(i + lineLength, base64EncodedImage.length());
            buf.append(base64EncodedImage.substring(i, end))
                .append("\r\n");
        }
        buf.append("\r\n")
        .append("--boundary_text\r\n")
        .append("--boundary_text--\r\n");
sendCommand(writer, buf.toString());

private static void sendCommand(BufferedWriter writer, String command) throws IOException {
    buffer.delete(0, buffer.length());
    buffer.append(command);
    buffer.append("\r\n");
    log.debug("command ::>> {}", command);
    writer.write(buffer.toString());
    writer.flush();
}

private static String base64EncodeImage(MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        byte[] imageBytes = file.getBytes();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }
}
```

I tried changing the content type, png to jpg, but it failed.

Comment: "they are delivered abnormally" what do you mean? Are you seeing the wrong image? No image? The email doesn't get delivered at all? Please describe what exact problem you're encountering.

Comment: How are you sending email? If you're using JakartaMail, then it does the encoding to base64 (or another transfer-encoding) for you, you don't need to (nor should you) do it yourself.

Comment: Never mind, I see that you're doing it yourself. The problem is that you're not following the [requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-24) of the email protocol. You need to use `Base64.getMimeEncoder(76, new byte[] { 0x0d, 0x0a })`, not the regular encoder.

Comment: But you really shouldn't reinvent the wheel, use JakartaMail.

Comment: Yes, make your life a lot easier with `return Base64.getMimeEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);`

Comment: @g00se Hah, I had entirely missed that variant, that is indeed easier than my suggestion.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sometimes the mail is delivered successfully, sometimes it isn't.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It's being sent to a socket.

Comment: All mail gets delivered via a socket ultimately ;) The point is that you should avoid complex low-level code when you can use simpler, higher level code. All sorts of things could be going on at the IO/network level that we can't see from the code you gave us